# Error starting fresh play 2.1 project

Tags: java, playframework-2.1

I am using play framework 2.1.0, I have created fresh project using command play new myfirstapp, then I selected 2 option to create simple java project and thus it created project

Now when I start play by command play run I get following output

```
C:\development\application\firstApp\helloworld>play run
[info] Loading project definition from C:\development\application\firstApp\helloworld\project
[info] Set current project to helloworld (in build file:/C:/development/application/firstApp/helloworld/)


Cannot load the JNotify native library (C:\development\Play%20framework\repository\local\net.contentobjects.jnotify\jnotify\0.94\jars\jnotify.jar (The system cannot find the file specified))
Play will check file changes for each request, so expect degraded reloading performace.

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

Now when I hit localhost:9000 it gives me following **exception** on web browser

please find the image here:

[image]

It has become bottle neck for me to go further, kindly help me out with this problem.
Some more information about my workstation

- Its windows 8 64 bit
- JDK 7

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should try to put Play in a path without space (C:\development\playframework).

Play2 + windows + spaces are not good friends ;)

Comment: Thanks @Julien Lafont it worked. I wasted 2 days behind this problem. I wish to vote-up but don't have enough reputation to vote up :(

Answer (score -1):

Open IIS by going to the start menu and writing `IIS (INTERNET INFORMATION SERVICE)`, stop the service and then refresh the page (F5).